# Finder freezes after updating to OS X 10.10.4

Tags: macos, finder, software-update, performance

The Finder is unresponsive after booting ever since I've updated to OS X 10.10.4. It takes a couple of minutes until it is ready. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it helped to remove the application state of the Finder. This command will move the state file to your desktop:

```
mv -r ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.finder.savedState ~/Desktop/com.apple.finder.savedState
```

Then restart the Finder process with `killall Finder`. If that was successful and you don't need anything from the old state file on your desktop (like a list of the opened windows from the last session), you can move it to the trash.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading to 10.10.4. Repeatedly started in safe mode and tried removing various things, including moving the saved state for Finder as suggested by mcb.

What eventually helped was to remove ITunesHelper from Login Items.

Open up Users & Groups from System Preferences, select your account and click Login Items, from there select ITunesHelper and click the button with a minus sign below the list, reboot back to normal mode and login.